# Conflict with 'IAsyncEnumerable<T>' in Unity When Integrating OpenAI GPT API Wrapper

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine, json.net, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am currently working on a Unity 2D game project (version 2022.2.6f1) where I'm trying to integrate the OpenAI GPT-3 API using an C#/.NET wrapper library, version 1.6 https://github.com/OkGoDoIt/OpenAI-API-dotnet. This wrapper requires .NET Standard 2.0 but my project's API compatibility level is .NET Standard 2.1, this may be the issue but I am not sure, I also don't know if that's fixable. I'm encountering an issue with 'IAsyncEnumerable' that seems to exist in both 'System.Interactive.Async' and 'netstandard'. Here is the exact error I'm getting:

> Assets\3rd Party\OkGoDoIt\OpenAI_API\Completions\CompletionEndpoint.cs(153,10): error CS0433: The type 'IAsyncEnumerable' exists in both 'System.Interactive.Async, Version=3.0.1000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263' and 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

I've added the Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.1 dll file and the 1.6 version of the chat GPT wrapper folder OpenAI_API to the assets of my Unity project. In the Player preferences API compatibility level in Unity I tried to go from .NET Standard 2.1 to the only other choice i have there: .NET Framework but it didn't change anything. I tried changing the .csproj so I can make an alias and force my project to always use IAsyncEnumerable from only System.Interactive.Async but every code I write there Unity just reloads it to the previous version.

Comment: FWIW, `System.Interactive.Async` is not part of .NET, it's a third-party library from ReactiveX. If your project isn't already using ReactiveX then you don't need to add a reference to `System.Interactive.Async`.

Comment: how exactly did you install this?

Comment: @derHugo I downloaded the archive from Open AI API and dragged into Assets the needed folder. I followed the steps from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gI9QSHpiMW0&t=1923s. The same thing for Newtonsoft.Json I got it from official github page, dragged and dropped the .dll file into assets. Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: Newtonsoft you can actually install via [Package Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@3.0/manual/index.html)

Comment: @derHugo I tried, but for some reason I cannot find it there

Comment: just try `+` -> `Add package by name` -> `com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json`

Comment: @derHugo that worked, thanks. Unfortunately, I still have my type 'IAsyncEnumerable' exists in both error

Comment: You need to remove the unnecessary references

Comment: @Charlieface I tried deleting in visual studio the System.Interactive.Async dll, but then I go to Unity, the errors are still there, I double click them and then the dll is restored in the visual studio project and nothing changes.

Comment: So I just scanned a bit through the repository and the `OpenAIAPI` already contains a `csproj` which references `Newtosoft` ... Unity doesn't play well with nuget referenced projects ... I would try to remove the `csproj` from `OpenAIAPI` and if dlls ar missing drag these in manually or alternatively you could try and use [NuGetForUnity](https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity) and install the whole thing this way